# How to create rank column in Python based on other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, running-count

I have a python dataframe that looks like the following:

[image]

This dataframe has been sorted in descending order by `'transaction_count'`. I want to create another column in that dataframe called `'rank'` that contains the count of occurrences of `cust_ID`. My desired output would look something like the following:

[image]

For `cust_ID = 1234` with `transaction_count = 4`, the rank would be 1, for the next appearance of `cust_ID = 1234`, the rank would be 2 and so on.

I tried the following among other things:

```
df['rank'] = df["cust_ID"].value_counts()
df.head(10)
```

But the rank column gets created as all NaN values

[image]

Any suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('cust_ID').cumcount() + 1
print(df['rank'])
```

**Output**

```
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    3
Name: rank, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('cust_ID')['transaction_count'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
    cust_ID     associate_ID    transaction_count   rank
0   1234           608          4                   1.0
1   1234           785          1                   2.0
2   4789           345          2                   1.0
3   3456           268          5                   1.0
4   3456           725          3                   2.0
5   3456           795          1                   3.0
```

Note that this gives not only the counts, but also the rank of the transaction, based on the `transaction_count` value.